# Why does adding an ID to p tag in WordPress footer make it invisible?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site. In the footer.php I put this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
echo "<p>There are currently {$user_count} members!</p>";
```

which works as intended (to display number of registered members).

Now I wanted to prepare it for CSS styling, so I tried to add an ID to the `<p>` tag so that I could target it in the CSS afterward. I also placed a span around the number itself because I wanted it to be a different color. My code:

```
global $wpdb;
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
echo "<p id="memberCount">There are currently <span id="memberCountNumber">{$user_count}</span> members!</p>";`
```

However, doing this just caused the message to disappear from the footer entirely. What am I doing wrong and how may it be fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: Because concatenation matters. Do it properly. Else you'll be getting error on your site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the ID, the problem is that those are unescaped double quotes in a string. They need to be replaced with escaped quotes `\"` or single quotes `'`.

PHP is trying to interpret `memberCount` and `memberCountNumber` itself, instead of considering them as a part of the string.

Comment: Thank you, I'm simultaneously grateful and embarrassed to hear that the answer is so simple. That fixed it up. Will mark as solved as soon as I'm able, have a good one!